# Как спарсить данные с сайта, который работает на react?

Tags: парсер, reactjs

Есть такой сайт https://csgomagic.com/
Если нажать на кнопку "CHOOSE SKIN" - http://joxi.net/82QOwdMS1Nqd4r появляется список скинов, который нужно спарсить.

До этого я работал с сайтами в которых при клике отправлялся запрос к api. Так было намного проще.
А в этом случае я впервые столкнулся с React и без понятия как получить эти данные.

Помогите, пожалуйста, или хотябы подскажите куда копать.

Comment: Если это React, то с близкой к единице вероятностью при клике тоже отправляется запрос к api. Как вы пришли к выводу, что это не так?

Comment: Вы явно нарушаете их terms of usage с которыми согласились при регистрации. Лесом пожалуйста.

Comment: @andreymal в инспекторе не вижу никакого запроса к апи и еще использовал это
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-sniffer/ndfgffclcpdbgghfgkmooklaendohaef
и никаких результатов

Comment: Просят помочь с парсом сайта который явно это запрещает.

Comment: Если что, то там почти весь сайт на https://socket.io построен.

Comment: @Ares God а как Вы определили это? Socket.io Devtool говорит что No global `io` detected...
тогда как React Developer Tools отображает React Object

Comment: @MikeReacher, https://snag.gy/zWZUbg.jpg , https://snag.gy/jk6xMi.jpg , https://snag.gy/TbOftN.jpg

Comment: @Ares God, Нужные мне данные я нашел с помощью React Developer Tools в Props. Они в rows массиве лежат. Только вот я React не шарю и без понятия как их получить. И появляются они в React Developer Tools только если на кнопку нажать. Если бы при нажатии запрос хоть какой то появлялся проблем бы не было

Comment: @Ares God это маловероятно

Comment: @Ares God в чем соль? Для меня єто пока что магия

Comment: @MikeReacher, все было проще чем вы думали:) https://snag.gy/PtKnAi.jpg

Comment: @MikeReacher, и если вам интересно, то они передаются по socket и сохраняются в localstorage (https://snag.gy/ZVYMBX.jpg)

Comment: @Ares God конечно интерестно. Вы гений, спасибо!!!
Из localstorage данные только с помощью js можно получить или на php можно?

Comment: @MikeReacher, только с помощью JS. Но ничто не мешает вам подключится к WebSocket без их сайта: например https://websocket.org/echo.html в location вбейте: `wss://csgomagic.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket` ;В PHP юзайте `fsockopen`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71533/discussion-between-mike-reacher-and-ares-god).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например при помощи headless-chrome https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome. Есть много разных утилит и библиотек для отрисовки JS сайтов на стороне разработчика (например, phantomjs). Тоесть сначала идет загрузка веб-сайта вашей средой, затем его отрисовка с вашей стороны (вывод на экран не обязателен), а затем парсинг отрисованный страницы (в том числе с возможностью автоматизированной симуляции действий пользователя).